# How to embed extra information in a View in android?

Tags: android

I am beginning android development and in my sample application I have a ListView which I populate as follows:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getEntityLabels());
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The `getEntityLabels()` is a function that returns a list of strings.

In the underlying model, the labels are not unique. Instead each entity has an `id` field which is unique for every entity.

```
class Entity{
  int id;
  String label;
}
```

When the user clicks on an item in the ListView, I would like to do some processing. So, I added an ItemClickListener as follows:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
{               
      //I would like to get the Id of the Entity, not just the label
}});
```

The processing depends on the `id` of the entity. However, as the view in the list is just a text and contains only the label, I cannot access it.

Is there a way to embed some information like id(in my case) with the views or an alternate way to get the `id`s?

I am aware of the way where I can override the `toString()` method of `Entity` to return label and use `ArrayAdapter<Entity>` instead of `ArrayAdapter<String>`. However, I am not looking for this. I am looking for a more generic way where I can embed any information with any View, if possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tags and assign tag to each view set in your adapter. Then you can read your tag from clicked view in OnClickListener and proceed. As tag can be anything (Object) you like that should solve your problem. See [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) and related.

Comment: And casting it when you call the get Method like `MyObject mObject = (MyObject) view.getTag();`